# Calling procedure from package in JOBS

Tags: oracle, plsql, jobs, oracle-sqldeveloper

[image]

I work in Oracle SQL Developer, I made a package "XXX" and a procedure `UPDATE_CUSTOMERS_RECORDS` in the package body. I tested this procedure and it worked.

But I want to call this procedure in JOBS. I make a job, and in “Type of Job” I choose `PL/SQL Block` option and type `MERITUM.update_customers_records()` but it doesn't work:

```
"ORA-06550: line ORA-06550: line 1, column 506:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "" when expecting one of the following:

   := . ( % ;
The symbol ";" was substituted for "" to continue.
, column :"
```

I tried also `call MERITUM.update_customers_records()` but with the same error.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
MERITUM.update_customers_records();
```

`;` should be used.

Comment: is the error the same? Try to use dbms_job.submit (or dbms_scheduler if you're experienced in it) - may be the issue is in OracleSQLDeveloper itself.

Answer (score 0):

J found a solution. Instead

```
MERITUM.update_customers_records();
```

in `PL/SQL Block` i put

```
declare
begin
  MERITUM.update_customers_records();
end;
```

end finally works :)

Comment: You don't need the `DECLARE` if you're not declaring any local variables. Just use the `BEGIN` and `END`.

Comment: It's very strange because all oracle examples don't use begin end because these clauses should be added implicit either by dbms_job or dbms_scheduler...